# Typescript error: error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.

Tags: typescript

Typescript error
error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.

I am getting this error when I am trying to compile any function with async await in it. My tsconfig.json file is this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [ "es2015" ],
    "module":"commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution" : "node",
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "includes" : [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Please help

Comment: I have tried other methods in git and stack.
I have version 8 node and version 3 typescript.

Comment: Typescript version 3 is still in development, are you sure you have 3.0 ? Also the tsconfig.json is not valid, it has two `module` entries

Comment: I deleted one of them

Comment: Sorry I have 2.9.2 typescript. Sorry

Comment: The compiled js is good and running.Though the output is coming the error is still throwing up.

Comment: The config looks good and should work with async/await, in fact I tested it, and except for the fact that it does not include all needed libs for common tasks, such as console and dom, it works fine,(fyi, you should also include dom and scriphost `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom", "scripthost" ],`). Are you sure this is the config being used ?

Comment: Yes. This is the only config file I have since I have just started coding in typescript and also there is only one folder in which everything is present

Comment: And how do you runt the compiler ?

Comment: BTW thanks for your replies

Comment: I run it in the command prompt
'tsc filename.ts'

Comment: Ah, there is the issue :), just run `tsc` without parameters in the project directory for the tsconfig to be picked up or `tsc -p path_to_tsconfig.json`, otherwise the compiler will take the default settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As se discussed in the comment, you are running the compiler in the command line by specifying the files :

```
tsc filename.ts
```

This actually means the compiler will not take into account your `tsconfig.json` file, it will expect that you specify the all the settings at the command line.

If you want to use a project configuration file (aka `tsocnfig.json`) you must either specify it explicitly using the `-p` option. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for compiler options.

```
tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

Or if you run the compiler directly in the project dir where the `tsconfig.json` is located you can just run the compiler without any options and it will pick the project file named `tsconfig.json` in the current directory

```
tsc
```